# Netbeans not showing pages with the last css markup

Tags: css, caching, netbeans

I am developing a web page on NetBeans, and I am using CSS file to style that page. When I run the page from NetBeans it is not applying my recent change to the CSS (in my case, a background color).

But if I run the page from my directory using Chrome, it all goes fine, and the last addition on the CSS file becomes visible on my web page.

Does anyone know the solution? I guess netbeans is caching alot, and does not get the last addition on my file?

I already deleted the cache folder at: `C:\Users\martins0011\AppData\Local\NetBeans`
but it still didn't work.

Comment: fixed thanks, I created another css file and on my html file I used that new CSS file.. dont know why dont work with the other :s
thanks anyway..

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below and then accept it.  That way, it's "closed out" and out of the queue so other questions can get prioritized.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed thanks, I created another css file and on my html file I used that new CSS file.. dont know why dont work with the other :s thanks anyway..